# Strange leveling problem by PrusaI3

Tags: heated-bed

I have a PrusaI3(Chinese kit that I assembled myself). my strange problem is that: when I try to leveling the bed, upper-left and bottom-right corners of the bed, are more far than the nozzle, respect to upper-right and bottom-left.

I don't know why, but I can't level them with the screws(because upper-left and bottom-right screws goes to be free sooner than their opposite side screws!!). I thought maybe the heated bed is not flat but I use a glass upon it! and it's not possible both of them are not flat!

EDIT: I can remember the last time I used my printer, there was a knocking sound when Y-AXIS was moving about the half of it's way. I very tried to find the cause of knocking sound but I couldn't. now, I have opened the heating bed and there is no sound when I move Y-Axis by hand. 
I hope you can understand me and help me too!

EDIT2: I did measure the rods and bed corners, I found that this corner(pointed by finger) is about 2 millimeters lower than other 3 corners! (It seems the bed part is not flat).

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: If the bed base is physically bent, then you are best off replacing it.  Trying to bend or press it flat is unlikely to work.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I don't know really if its bent. because it's ok when I see by eyes. but when I measure the height of corners, one of them is about 2mm lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by this strange system for both opposite sides but I couldn't find the really reson of this problem!:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Prusha I3 design uses two rods to guide the Y axis, which moves along the rods on linear bearings.  If the rods are not strictly planar, there will be movement of the bed as it moves to and fro.  You would not be able to correct this with the leveling screws.

Be sure that the rods are planar, and that there is no torque on the bed from uneven rods.  Even if the bed doesn't flex, the frame may flex if the rods are not planar.

Comment: But how can I find the problem? I did open the bed and the Y-Axis belt, it seems it moves smoothly by hand and I can't detect any problem by eyes!

Comment: I can remember the last time I used my printer, there was a knocking sound when Y-AXIS was moving about the half of it's way. I very tried to find the cause of knocking sound but I couldn't. now, I have opened the heating bed and there is no sound when I move Y-Axis by hand.

Comment: The Y-xis bearing-rods must be planar.  You can evaluate that in several ways.  The easiest might be to remove the bed completely to fully expose the rods.  Lay a known-flat material on the bearing-rods, and verify that it lies completely flat against the rods, touching evenly along the length of both rods.  If there is any gap, or the object rocks, then the bearing-rods are not planar, and that should be fixed, such as by adjusting the threaded rods that support the bearing-rod ends.

Comment: What is the carriage made of?  Is that completely flat?

Comment: When the carriage moves forward and back, watch the bearing rods and the rest of the mechanism carefully.  There should be absolutely NO movement, other than the motion of the carriage.

Answer (score 1):

How did you measure the bed corners (caliper, ruler, spirit-level)?
I had a similar problem in my 3d printer (Geetech Prusa REpRap I3) I solved by using an indicator (distance amplifying instrument). what I did was to set-up my heating bed completely, with the glass, screws with spacers, springs.
I had fix on the z-axis my indicator set to 0, and I started moving the printer with small increments to each corner of the bed, slowing adjusting each corner screw to keep my bed on level. It is a very dull and time consuming process, but, now I have an offset from one corner to the other of just 30 µm.

Keep in mind that during a normal printing, the heating bed due to thermal expansion may increase the deviation of your calibration step.

If you have any doubts do not hesitate to ask!
Cheers

Comment: Hello, and thanks for help. If it isn't hard for you, may you take some photos from what you did? or post the photo of the part you bought?

Comment: I did measure the corners by simple ruler

Comment: Yes @user145959, Right now i am at work, as soon as I get in my home i will send some photos of how i did my calibration!